# Trying to customize NGUI - UIButton in the Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

When I try to customize a class of "NGUI - UIButton",
I got a problem that's not working serialize variables in Unity editor inspector view.

```c#
public class MyButton : UIButton // inherited NGUIButton class
{
    public bool _isChecked;
    public int _count;
}
```

I can't see the variables in the inspector of Unity editor.

**How can I see the variables in inspector?**

I was trying it with `[serializeField]` script too.
But it's also not working

Is there something special about NGUI?

Comment: my projects has not any errors. VS works great. just can't see that in inspector

Comment: don't know NGUI and how ecaxtly it works ... you could try to set `[Serializable]` before the class definition.